# CDH 5.3 from Cloudera Manager installtion hangs on Refresh Package Metadata

Tags: hadoop, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

I am using cloudera manger to intall CDH5, on a cluster of 1 master and 3 nodes. 
i get to the stage below and it hangs on refreshing data

[image]

the details show that it is performing this command

```
BEGIN yum makecache 
Loaded plugins: refresh-packagekit, security
```

it hangs.
but when i ran the command BEGIN yum makecache on each node and it runs well.

the master went pass this stage with not errors hence you see just the nodes are the ones that are currently installing. 
can anyone help me determine what is wrong? is it something wrong with the configuration of the nodes?